# How programmers design their iOS apps

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I'm a beginner in iOS development. I have followed many tutorials on many websites, and I started to understand greatly how the different files and data models work.

Though, I can't understand how views are designed. From the basics Interface Builder views, and how they are designed. Are these complex designs made with code? With the Interface Builder? With both?

For example, look at those screenshots:
http://inspired-ui.com/tagged/app_sosh#show-all

And particularly this one:

http://40.media.tumblr.com/a19dec9c6f3892b7884e23c608883a05/tumblr_n9ud81hizB1r71i1jo1_400.png

Someone told me that was a `UITableView` view, but if it's true, how can they code a map at the top? How does this map can scroll with the rest of the following tableview cells?

What's more, it seems to be a grouped style `UITableView`. How can they design it? Personally I didn't found in IB much parameters that allow me to change so many things. And I looked for a code solution, but I didn't find something clear and easy.

As you can see, I'm a little bit lost. May you guide me?

Comment: Where I work we have designers that design our apps and developers that develop them. For personal apps I don't normally put that much design effort in, I'll normally just create something and if I like it I will keep it, all about trial and error. However there are design apps/sites you can use like http://www.appdesigner.com/download/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the views you are describing in the image, there are a number of ways to achieve those UI's. My suggestion is to go and play about with adding multiple views in a view controller and looking at Apple's [iOS documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/navigation/) to see what you can do with it.

For this image,

[image: View Design]

I personally would opt to have a `UITableView` with multiple sections. In the first (0th index) section, I'd implement a custom `UITableViewCell` which contains an `MKMapView` so that the map scrolls with the table in it's own custom cell.

You can build this out with interface builder which would look like below:

[image: IB View]

Whilst this a quick and rough implementation, it should give you a good starting point to play around with it.

I really do suggest playing around with the Interface Builder to see what you can do. Start with more trivial views and then work your way up to things that are more complicated.

Comment: Thank's for the example ! I'll take your advice and experiment more IB by myself.

Comment: This is a really good answer. Well done.

Comment: Thanks :) and thanks for the edits as well. Much appreciated.